# Don't you need an object name to pass into the constructor? "new Class()" isn't an object yet

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, composition

I've been supplementing my school course work with some Udemy courses.  I'm trying to understand one example right now for intermediate C# and I'm a little confused about one of the details.  I understand inheritance, but I'm a little confused about composition (specifically passing objects to objects and where they are initialized).  In this example there is a DbMigrator class, Installer Class, and a Logger class that DbMigrator and Installer both borrow from.  Here is Main:

```
namespace Composition 
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Logger());
            var logger = new Logger();
            var installer = new Installer(logger);

            dbMigrator.Migrate();
            installer.Install();
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the part where you create a logger object that is passed to the installer object, but I don't get the "new Logger()" constructor for dbMigrator object because there is no variable name for the logger that is being created.  Wouldn't you need to create "var logger1 = new Logger()" inside the dbMigrator object's constructor? I don't understand how you can just pass "new logger()" without a variable name.

Here is the DbMigrator class:

```
namespace Composition
{
    public class DbMigrator
    {
        private readonly Logger _logger;
        public DbMigrator(Logger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Migrate()
        {
            _logger.log = ("Blah blah blah");
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that the DbMigrator class has one initialized, but I would think an object needs to be created first.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question. Are you asking why, inside the `DbMigrator` class and/or constructor, before you assign `_logger = logger;`, why you don't have a `_logger = new Logger();` ? Please try to be more specific about exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: `no object name for the logger` - I think you mean no _variable_ for the logger. That makes no difference - there's no requirement that you must have a local variable which references an object.

Comment: Yes, variable name for the object.

Comment: The 'new' is what creates the object. It's just that there isn't a reference to it within the calling code. In other words, when you do 'var Logger = new Logger();' you are doing _two_ things - creating an object, and creating a reference to it.

Comment: There are two variables at play in the `DbMigrator` constructor, the parameter to the constructor, `logger`, and the field in the class, `_logger`.

Comment: So, "new Class()" is sufficient to create an object of that type without a variable?

Comment: Your variable name is essentially `logger` from your `DbMigrator` `class`

Comment: The expression `new Class(...)` constructs a new object instance of the type `Class`, and returns the reference to this object. The assignment `var logger = ...` is what is declaring a variable and assigning that reference to the variable.

Comment: @JohanP Yes, I understand that, but it's the sequence of events.  It doesn't become _logger fireld until it gets passed.  It needs an object passed before it can become the _logger field

Comment: Great ok - think of `new Logger()` as just a statement which outputs something. In the same way that `1+1` outputs a number. Specifically though, it outputs a newly created `Logger` object. That output can be used anywhere that'll accept it - by a variable, or as a method argument (which in turn includes constructors - they're just special methods).

Comment: I think that if you think of types as blueprints for a house, an object as an actual house someone built from a blueprint, the address of the house as a reference and a post-it note with the address written on it as a variable it *might* become clearer.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Okay, that makes more sense.  So the variable name is just the reference to the object that was created.   But, an object was created regardless of whether there is a variable reference to it.  Is that correct?

Comment: if you do `new Logger()` a new instance will get created on the heap but nothing will point to it, which means it will get `GC'd` when that method runs its course. When you pass `new Logger()` to `DbMigrator`, the same happens but `logger` is sitting on the stack pointing to that instance.

Comment: Okay, thanks everybody.  I get it now!  Very informative.

Comment: @schulzey Yep that's correct - `new Logger();` is a perfectly valid statement (with nothing else around it). If there's no references at all then it'll get garbage collected (but passing it to a method etc is a reference too - you've essentially just got a reference on the stack instead of in e.g. a local variable or in a field).

Comment: @LukeBriggs Okay, yeah that makes sense.  I'm getting into more of the details of OOP.  I haven't been in the situation yet where I've passed an object to a constructor without a variable name.  I was pretty confused.  I've always set a new variable equal to the instance of a class in the past.  I'm glad I asked this question.

Comment: Btw, it's likely that the logger should be instantiated *once* at the beginning, so that both classes get the same instance.

Comment: Also FWIW the code quoted above doesn't actually compile so that could also be something that was throwing you off - specifically `logger.log = ("Blah blah blah");` should probably be `_logger.log("Blah blah blah");`

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't type it correctly.  It is suppose to be _logger.log.  It was the concept that was throwing me.  I'm all about fundamentals for learning and I want to make sure I have a very solid foundation on all of these principles for when things get really complicated.

Comment: Great alright - that's certainly the best way to do it. If it would help I'll gladly drop some more details about the stack etc as an answer (although I've just got to head out so I'd be back in half an hour or so :) )

Comment: @LukeBriggs  Yes, please! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So firstly, a summary of the question - how come this works?

```
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Logger());
```

Shouldn't it be this?

```
var logger = new Logger();
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(logger);
```

A fully detailed answer is quite long, so I'll try my best to make it nice and easy to follow. We'll do that by first describing what an *expression* is and how they work in C# (more broadly, how they work in any stack based language - fortunately that's almost all of the ones you've heard of!)

## Expressions, statements and operations.. what?

**An operation:** Something like add, subtract etc.

**An expression:** A bunch of *operations*. `1+2+3` or just a constant like `1` or `"hi!"`

**A statement:** Usually one expression followed by a `;` but something like an `if` or a `while` loop are also statements. If a program was a cooking recipe, a statement is simply one of the steps.

Let's take a quick look at that in C#:

```
int totalPrice=1+2*3;
```

That's one statement and it's broken down into *operations* like this:

- Multiply 2 by 3
- Add 1
- Set the result into a local variable called `totalPrice`

A great question to ask at this point is then this:

*So right after `Multiply 2 by 3` runs, where is the 6 stored?*

Answer: **The stack.** More on that shortly!

## Quick extra notes on methods

Method calls like `Hello("all!");` accept *expressions* as arguments. `Hello(1+1;);` fails, because that's a statement in there. `Hello(1+(2*3));` is fine though.

## Operations

Each *operation* takes in any number of *operands* then optionally *outputs something*. For example, the multiply operation takes in 2 operands - A * B - then outputs whatever they were multiplied together. `new Something()` takes in any number of constructor arguments and outputs a *reference* to the newly created object.

Here's the important part.

**The output of an operation always goes onto the stack. The inputs are always put onto the stack first too.**

## So what's this stack thing?

A full [stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) is out of scope here - if you're interested in the full details then check out e.g. [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language). The quick summary is all C based languages use this same concept. Let's revisit that C# statement above and describe it in stack operations:

```
int totalPrice=1+2*3;
```

- Push 2 onto the stack

  *The stack is now just [2]*
- Push 3 onto the stack

  *The stack is now [2,3]*
- Multiply (Pops off two values from the stack and multiplies them)

  *The stack is now [6]*
- Push 1 onto the stack

  *The stack is now [6,1]*
- Add (Pops off two values from the stack, adds them together)

  *The stack is now [7]*
- Store in local `totalPrice` (pops off the stack value and stores it)

  *The stack is now empty*

*Side note: These stack operations are what the C# compiler generates. It's called [CIL or .NET IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).*

## The call stack

**Health warning!** The call stack is something totally different. It's the call stack that can "overflow".

## What about the original statement?

Alright so hopefully we've covered enough ground for this part to make more sense! So let's take the original statement:

```
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Logger());
```

Firstly, the `new` operation is just like any other method call - all the arguments are pushed onto the stack, the method is invoked (popping them all off the stack) and the return value is then put on the stack.

So, here it is described stack style:

- New Logger Object (Creates a Logger object on the heap and puts a reference to it on the stack. No args so it doesn't pop anything)

  *Stack is now [a logger reference]*
- New DBMigrator Object (Pops the 1 arg off, pushes the reference)

  *Stack is now [a DBMigrator reference]*
- Store in local `dbMigrator`

  *Stack is now empty*

To really cement that in, compare it to the alternative (which is also valid):

```
var logger = new Logger();
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(logger);
```

- New Logger Object

  *Stack is now [a logger reference]*
- Store in local `logger`

  *Stack is now empty*
- Load local `logger`

  *Stack is now [a logger reference]*
- New DbMigrator Object

  *Stack is now [a DBMigrator reference]*
- Store in local `dbMigrator`

  *Stack is now empty*

**What you also just learned:** They both work, but the second one is slightly slower - it does *more*. Looking at those stack operations, it appears to do something completely pointless - It's like you just put something in a filing cabinet, then immediately take it out again!

## When should locals be used over the stack?

As a quick side note, there are languages that don't have locals and only use the stack. They can be hugely optimized and tend to go faster, but they're also harder to write. Locals are great when you need multiple references to something:

```
Logger logger=new Logger();
// Using it twice!
logger.A();
logger.B();
```

If you were only using it once, then this is perfectly valid too:

```
(new Logger()).A();
```

**Bonus round:** Let's say that method `A` did `return this;` resulting in a reference to that Logger object on the stack again. That'll let us do this:

```
(new Logger()).A().B();
```

This is *method chaining* - it's related to *functional programming* and is getting increasingly more common because of how compact it is.

## Summary

Local variables aren't the only way of storing things - the stack does it too! You don't need to keep track of the stack - the compiler does all of that for you. You just need think about those input/ output values.

Comment: @schulzey no problem! I tried to go with a route that should have you covered for a wide range of languages beyond just C# (Javascript, Java, C++, PHP etc - they all do the same thing) - hopefully it all makes sense!